# How to handle multiple layers for get an unify attribute table?

Tags: qgis

I am working with other people making shape files with the same attributes on QGis.
I need an unify attribute table of this group of layers in csv for processing the data.

For now we add the shapefiles to a common folder and we merge the new layers with a unify vector layer. This makes problems when someone are using the unify layer, with simultaneous merges or if in any process the unify layer get broken. 
I am new with GIS and I don't know all tools, There is other way for solve this or for create an attribute table of multiple layers?

The solution could be simple with some tool, but my knowledge of QGIS is limited.

Comment: The solution is "save a new version of the file with date every time you unify it". This is at least the better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a .csv file you can open the unified vector layer, Right-click -> Export -> Save As and choose 'Comma Separated Value' as a file format.

The problem is you will have to resave every time the vector layer is changed if you need that new data.